# Creating Unique Dropdown In Excel Based on existing data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table in Excel 2010 with transaction data dating many years.

I would like to create an in-cell drop-down of the unique **years** in the POSTDATE column and populate those right above that column, outside of the table. I will use that as input to a conditional format later...

I have tried by going to:

- Data Validation
- Setting the Allow to List,
- Setting the Source = "=YEAR($E$12:$E$5763)" (gives error)

If I remove the YEAR from that formula then I get every single date. I just want the unique years. Trying to do this without VBA, just an in-cell drop-down... Is this the wrong way to go about it?

Screen snip below is from the much larger table of data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Say we have:

[image]

and we:

1. want unique years to make a `DV`
2. don't want to use VBA
3. can't use the `AGGREGATE()` worksheet function

In **I2** enter:

```
=YEAR(H2)
```

and copy downward.  In **J2** enter:

```
=I2
```

In **J3** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I$2:I3,I3)=1,I3,"")
```

and copy downward.  In **K2** enter the **array formula**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(J$2:J$21,SMALL((IF(LEN(J$2:J$21),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(J$2:J$21))))),ROW(A1)),1),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Trying to translate the formulas to my sheet. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I used your data (well, the same amount of rows) and it worked. When I tried it with my table (5759 rows so far) it didnt work. The helper1 column continue to show the year but the helper 2 column failed to produce any data. So I will have to investigate that - maybe I have an error in there somewhere.